# SFTP uploads file saved in Sublime Text, despite its parent folder being regex ignored

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm setting up a development workflow using Sublime Text 3 and the SFTP add-on. Within sftp-config.json I have appended the following two rules to the `"ignore_regexes"` key:

```
... "/src/", "/node_modules/"
```

Whenever I choose `Sync Local->Remote`, this successfully ignores these folders and all their contents. They have no place on the remote server. Further up, in sftp-config.json, i also have the following rule:

```
"upload_on_save": true,
```

This is because I'll be working on a number of PHP and JavaScript files, that I don't want to have to manually upload every time I save (there's going to be a lot of saving going on).

**However**:

The problem is that every time I save a file inside any directory under `src`, it uploads it along with every parent folder up until `src`. This is not what I want!

Clearly, the upload rule is overriding the ignore rule - and probably for good reason. So what do I need to do, in order to ignore every save for every file and folder within `src` etc, while still allowing files outside these folders to be automatically uploaded when saved?

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Comment: No, it still persists... I've learned to just live with it for now. Not ideal, I know.

Comment: I found ```"/src/*"``` worked.